# How to put selected date in TextBox from calendar in kivy?

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I am using `KivyCalendar`.When i choose date from `calendar` then it gives error.

```
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/uix/behaviors/button.py", line 151, in on_touch_down
     self.dispatch('on_press')
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 714, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy/_event.c:7681)
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1225, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch (kivy/_event.c:13524)
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1149, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch (kivy/_event.c:13050)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/KivyCalendar/calendar_ui.py", line 218, in get_btn_value
     self.parent_popup.dismiss()
 AttributeError: 'CalendarWidget' object has no attribute 'parent_popup'
```

Can someone tell me how to put value in `TextBox` after choose date from `calendar`?
Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated..!!

## demo.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from KivyCalendar import CalendarWidget
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.clearcolor = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)
Window.size = (400, 250)

class SetIndex(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SetIndex, self).__init__()
        #self.init_ui()

    def setDate(self):
        self.cal = CalendarWidget(as_popup=True)
        self.popup = Popup(title='Calendar', content=self.cal, size_hint=(1, 1))
        self.popup.open()


class Demo(App):
    def build(self):
        return SetIndex()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Demo().run()
```

## demo.kv

```
<SetIndex>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding : 20, 20
        size_hint_y: .5

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            padding: 10, 10
            spacing: 10, 10
            size_hint_x: .6

            Label:
                text: "TEXT"
                text_size: self.size
                valign: 'middle'
                size_hint_x: .2

            TextInput:
                size_hint_x: .4
                id: old_date
                on_focus: root.setDate()
```

Comment: whats is the error??

Comment: @eyllanesc thank you.I have updated error in question

Comment: According to what I see that library does not have recent update in pypi: 2015-06-14, probably have support problems, for example I have other errors, reports the bug to its creator